# vscode go cannot organize imports when save code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, gopls

I open the vscode language server `gopls`. And use Format Tool `default`(because prompts said others are not applicable when language server is enabled).

and config set:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": true
}
```

but my code imports are：

```
import (
    "net/http"

    "private.com/error"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)
```

When I save it, it doesn't add blank line between `private.com/error` and  `github.com/gin-gonic/gin` automatically, even though the vscode prompts it
[image]

How can I set it, it will organize import automatically ?

Comment: It seems like gopls is not organizing imports as expected. You can try updating gopls to the latest version with the following command:···GO111MODULE=on go get golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest···Then, restart VSCode and see if the issue is resolved. If the problem persists, you can consider reporting this as an issue on the gopls GitHub repository to seek further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

seems similar to the [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/3059)

try `"go.useLanguageServer": false` or the suggested config for `"[go]":`